# Do CSS pseudo classes get read before other selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

CSS reads from right to left, but are pseudo classes read before or after the selectors they are attached to?

For example, in:

```
p:first-child {}
```

Do browsers match every p-element, and then determine whether it's first-child, or does it match every first child of every element, and the determine whether it's a p-element?

I imagine browsers match the element, and then determines whether it's :first-child, :nth-child, etc., but I would like to be sure..

Comment: Did google not have an answer?

Comment: I think you're asking about implementation details. Implementations are really vague and can change even between versions if for some reason performance could improve or the code gets cleaner by choosing one over another.

Comment: I asked google; couldn't find it. Did find several places saying pseudo selectors are the slowest. http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-selector-performance/ But slowest doesn't really mean much unless you're pouring 10mb data tables out into the view.

Comment: Thanks Zenorbi, I will keep that in mind.
Thanks to Will, also, that article gives me a good idea of what I was looking for. Would you mind making your comment into an answer?

@alien: No, that's why I asked here. Did your comment help? No. Next time, how about you add something useful to the conversation when you make a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Do browsers match every p-element, and then determine whether it's
>   first-child, or does it match every first child of every element, and
>   the determine whether it's a p-element?"

Neither. The browser doesn't look for elements to apply the rules to, it looks for rules to apply to an element.

When checking if a rules applies to an element, it doesn't make much difference if it first checks whether it is a `p` element or whether it's the first child. Both are quite easy to determine.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Guffa, but I wasn't looking how to determine which rules apply to which elements. I was looking for whether when matching style rules to elements, if the match takes place first at the pseudo class, and then at the pseudo-class's qualifier, or if it looks at the qualifier first, and then the pseudo class.
I could see where my initial question could be misunderstood, though. My apologies for not having been clearer.

Comment: @user3633776: The right to left processing only applies across combinators, when it comes to the selectors in each compound selector that is just up to the implementation in the browser. It depends on the optimisations that the browser does which selectors are faster to check, but it has very little impact on the performance. The effect of checking the equivalents of `this.tagName == 'P'` or `this.parent.childNodes[0] == this` first is hardly possible to measure.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. Thank you very much for clarifying.